# Stored procedure to get the status of a linked server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, linked-server

I'm trying to create a stored procedure to get the status of a linked server to prevent errors when trying to execute anything on it. I saw some examples online, but I'm not having any success with those.

Here is my code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[checkLinkedServer] 
    @servername ntext
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @retval int = 0;
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC @retval = sys.sp_testlinkedserver @servername;
        SELECT 1;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT 0;
    END CATCH;      
END
```

I'm always getting a return value of 0 - no matter if the linked server exists or not.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried running it without the begin try, etc?

Comment: @ChrisBint Shows this: Msg 214, Level 16, State 90, Procedure sp_testlinkedserver, Line 1 Procedure expects parameter '@servername' of type 'sysname'.

Comment: Why is your parameter `ntext`? You know that this type was deprecated long ago, right? Did you try `sysname` (as the error message already suggested!) or `nvarchar(128)`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand i didn't know ... and now what it is the substitute type

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your @servername parameter needs to be of the type sysname not ntext as the error message says

If you can't change the parameter going into the procedure then consider creating a new variable inside the proc and doing a convert:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[checkLinkedServer] 
    @servername ntext
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @retval int = 0,
            @sysservername sysname;
    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT  @sysservername = CONVERT(sysname, @servername);
        EXEC @retval = sys.sp_testlinkedserver @sysservername;
        SELECT 1;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT 0;
    END CATCH;      
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the documentation and implementation for `sp_testlinkedserver` are inconsistent, and have been so since the procedure was added in SQL Server 2005. BOL says that the procedure **returns 1 on failure**.

For reference you can check : http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/522821/sp-testlinkedserver-fails-catastrophically-when-linked-server-is-offline

Comment: "We've discussed this among the team members and concluded that the best thing to do at this point is to fix BOL to match reality. ". i want to know exactly what means that ...

Comment: BOL means books online and the above statement means there team wants to fix the online books and documentation.